# How to create a file on system drive on windows 8.1 in c?

Tags: c, windows

Take a look at the code below, it works for drive d but not for c (system drive) - I guess it's because of some security restrictions but how to bypass them?

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
   FILE *fp;

   fp = fopen("c:\\test.txt", "w+");
   fprintf(fp, "This is testing for fprintf...\n");
   fputs("This is testing for fputs...\n", fp);
   fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: there is never a way to "bypass" security :) you need to run your code with elevated rights (i.e Administrator command prompt)

Comment: Right click the executable, and select Run As Administrator from the context menu.  ***[More on Run As Administrator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms717801%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)***

Answer (score 1):

You are going need to use Windows-specific ways to elevate the privileges of the task, and perform the operation. See [Developing Applications that Require Administrator Privilege](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd550643%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

On the other hand, your program should write only in locations where the user has the right to write files unless there is an exceptional reason to need to put a file in a location where doing so requires elevated privileges.